# beautifulsoup how to purposely add return none if element not found

Tags: dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I add `[none]` on purpose if the element is not found? I have an element that sometimes exists and sometimes won't. ([LINK HERE](https://www.nakedcph.com/sneakers-by-adidas/s/37))

Below current output in `df`:

```
name                       tag
ZX Torsion Releasing       Soon
Campus                     Restock
Campus                     Restock
Consortium Runner Mid 4D   Sold out
Ozweego                    Sold out
Ozweego                    Sold out
Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Infant  Sold out
Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Kids    Sold out
Yeezy Boost 350 V2         Sold out
Yung-1                     Sold out
Yung 1                     Sold out
A.R. Trainer               Sold out
A.R. Trainer               Sold out
```

Desired Output

```
name                      tag
ZX Torsion Releasing      Soon
Campus                    Restock
Campus                    Restock
Consortium Runner Mid 4D  null
Ozweego                   null
Ozweego                   null
Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Infant Sold out
Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Kids   Sold out
Yeezy Boost 350 V2        Sold out
Yung-1                    null
Yung 1                    null
A.R. Trainer              null
A.R. Trainer              null
....and so on
```

Working Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://www.nakedcph.com/sneakers-by-adidas/s/37'
] 

baseURL = 'https://www.nakedcph.com'
final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
        driver.get(url)
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        items  = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('col-6 col-md-3 mb-5')})
        name = [item.find('span',{'class':'product-name d-block'}).text.strip() for item in items]
        tag = [item.find('svg').next_sibling.strip() for item in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'card-ribbon'})]
        results = list(zip(name,tag))
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)

driver.quit()
df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `try except`. I've never incorporated it into a list comprehension, which I might try to go back and do:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

urls = [
    'https://www.nakedcph.com/sneakers-by-adidas/s/37'
] 

baseURL = 'https://www.nakedcph.com'
final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(url)
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        items  = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('col-6 col-md-3 mb-5')})

        name = []
        tag = []
        for each in items:
            name.append(each.find('span',{'class':'product-name d-block'}).text.strip())
            try:
                tag.append(each.find('svg').next_sibling.strip())
            except:
                tag.append(None)
        results = list(zip(name,tag))
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                            0               1
0                  ZX Torsion  Releasing Soon
1                      Campus         Restock
2                      Campus         Restock
3    Consortium Runner Mid 4D            None
4                     Ozweego            None
5                     Ozweego            None
6   Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Infant        Sold out
7     Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Kids        Sold out
8          Yeezy Boost 350 V2        Sold out
9                      Yung-1            None
10                     Yung 1            None
11               A.R. Trainer            None
12               A.R. Trainer            None
13             Adilette Pride            None
14                 Supercourt            None
15              Supercourt RX            None
16                 ZX 4000 4D            None
17         Yeezy Boost 700 V2        Sold out
18  Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Infant        Sold out
19    Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Kids        Sold out
20         Yeezy Boost 350 V2        Sold out
21         Yeezy Boost 700 V2        Sold out
22    Yeezy Boost 700 V2 Kids        Sold out
23  Yeezy Boost 700 V2 Infant        Sold out
```

Comment: @chitown98 is exception handling a better way to phrase for this type of question followed by data frame?just trying to improve my questions for future.

Comment: you could have maybe add that as a tag. I think the title and description of the question was fine though. you also provided what output you were getting, and what output you were trying to achieve with the complete code to re-produce it. So like I said, I thought the question was fine.